# Spring Boot Error creating bean with name entityManagerFactory

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have set up the spring application as follows, which keeps giving me an error

```
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' 
defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/query/BindableType
```

ITs a basic spring set up, without any classes, just config

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.15"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.15.RELEASE"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")

    //DB
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.23.1")
    implementation("com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-60:2.21.1")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
server.port=8090
# For liquibase use
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://test.com:5432/main
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=
spring.liquibase.enabled=false
spring.liquibase.liquibase-schema=test

# PostgreSQL
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=test
```

Comment: the problem seems to be this dependency
 com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-60, 
Not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 2.7.15 uses Hibernate 5.6.15.Final so you will need include com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-55 not com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-60.
hibernate-types-60 is used with Hibernate 6 only. BindableType is a Hibernate 6 class and is not present in Hibernate 5. My guess is that hibernate-type-60 uses the BindableType class.

You may want to migrate to hypersistence-utils-hibernate-55. See [this](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils) for information about why you may want to upgrade.